# Importing and merging files in loop

Tags: r, loops, directory, lapply, paste

I have to combine datasets. They are .sav files, and I have 6-7 datasets per month, per year - a total of 13 years. That's a lot of datasets to import and combine, and I want to automate this using loops.

As I'm a beginner, I wrote the first loop to simply combine the datasets for one year (so only looping over the months). This was my code, and it did what I wanted perfectly. It's not the fastest and for sure not the prettiest or most efficient, but it worked. Note: I shortened the "C..." path in the code posted for brevity: in my real code it's the full path.

```
 for (m in months) {
setwd(paste("C:.... survey\\DANE 2005\\",m,sep=""))
files_2005 <- list.files(path=(paste("C:\....survey\\DANE 2005\\",m,sep="")),  pattern=("Area.*.sav"))

#for (i in (paste("files_",m,sep=""))){
   df_2005 <- lapply(files_2005, read_sav)
  assign(paste("DANE2005_",m,sep=""), df_2005 %>% reduce(rbind.fill))

#}

df_2005 <- mget(ls(pattern="DANE2005_"))
dane_2005 <- df_2005 %>% reduce(rbind.fill)
```

}

And here is my current code, looping over years & months (thanks to  @Onyambu for the comments). However, it still does not work; if I dont use setwd R says that the "current file does not exist in the directory" (and refers back to my main directory, not the path specified). If I do use setwd, I get the "cannot change working directory" error.

```
for (y in years) {
  for (m in months) {

    #Go to a folder per year/month
    path <- paste("C:.... survey\\DANE ",y,"\\",m,sep="")
    #Create a list of all the files in that folder by month, based on a pattern
    list_data<-list.files(path=path,  pattern=("Area.*.sav"))

    if(!is_empty(list_data)){
    #Read in all the files in the folder by month, based on the list
    df_2005 <- lapply(list_data, read_sav)
    #bind the files for one month together based on the list
    assign(paste("DANE2005_",m,sep=""), df_2005 %>% reduce(rbind.fill))
    }
  }
  #Bind together all the files for one year
  df_2005 <- mget(ls(pattern="DANE2005_"))
  dane_2005 <- df_2005 %>% reduce(left_join)
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: cleaned up the code and re-posed the question for clarity after initial comments.

Comment: First your whole code is just a repetition. `path <-"C:...survey 2005"`. You do not need to `setwd` use ` list.dirs(path,full.names = TRUE,recursive=TRUE)` now use lapply to read this to your list. Thats all

Comment: @Onyambu, thank you! I did not know about list.dirs. Seems indeed perfect for this problem. But what exactly do you mean? Should I: 1) set the path (as is), and then 2) separately add `assign(assign(paste("df_",y,sep="")),(list.dirs(path, full.names=T,recursive=T)))`, OR should I replace your suggested code in place of paste in this piece of code: `lapply(paste("files_",y,sep="")`. I tried the second option, and I get the "Unable to open file" error. Thank you again!

Comment: you do not need to use `assign` nor do you need to use `paste`. since you need the files in the folders, use `s<-dir(path,recursive=TRUE,full.names=TRUE)` then do `mydat<-setNames(lapply(s, read.sav),basename(s))`.This reads all the data in all the folders to a list. If you want to include the month as a column, you should write a customized read.sav function instead

Comment: I took a good look at the code based on your comments and edited it. I re-posed the question above as it still gives me errors...

Comment: I am not quite sure whether you understood what I put across. So as to have space, I will give an answer then you will look at it and let me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to Try:

```
# give the path only to the folder where the years are inside the folder
path <- "C:.... survey"

# read all the files in this path using recursive = TRUE-Gives all years,all months,all files
all_files <- list.files(path, pattern = "Area.*.sav", full.names=TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

# Now read all these files into a list. Of course you would like to have the year and the month for the file:

my_read <- function(x){
      nm <- unlist(strsplit(sub(".*survey/","",x),"/"))# Remove everything until survey. You only remain with year,month and file name
      cbind(year = nm[1],month = nm[2],file = nm[3], read_sav(x))
    }

# Now use myl_read function in read the data:

  dat_list <- lapply(all_files,my_read)
```